# Problems adding DKMS support to kernel module

Tags: dynamic, module, kernel

I'm trying to add DKMS support in a kernel module i'm working on.

I have placed the kernel module source with a static lib to be linked against in the following directory:

```
/usr/src/dpx/1.0
```

With the following files:

```
dkms.conf
Makefile
dpxmtt.c
lib.a
```

dkms.conf file is like this:

```
MAKE="make"
CLEAN="make clean"
BUILT_MODULE_NAME=dpx
BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION=src/
DEST_MODULE_LOCATION=/kernel/drivers/input/touchscreen
PACKAGE_NAME=dpxm
PACKAGE_VERSION=1.0
REMAKE_INITRD=yes
```

And the makefile is like this:

```
EXTRA_CFLAGS+=-DLINUX_DRIVER -mhard-float

obj-m += dpx.o
dpx-objs:= dpxmtt.o ../source/lib.a

all:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

The ../source/lib.a is an hack since when the makefile is invoked by the dkms building system it was saying that it couldn't be found in directory (the build directory), but since it was being copied to the source directory, i'm referencing it relatively.

When I call

```
sudo dkms build -m dpx -v 1.0
```

The result is almost perfect:

```
santos@NS-PC:~$ sudo dkms build -m dpx -v 1.0

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel.  Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area....
make KERNELRELEASE=3.0.0-14-generic....
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for dpx: 1.0 not found
Error!  Build of dpx.ko failed for: 3.0.0-14-generic (i686)
Consult the make.log in the build directory
/var/lib/dkms/dpx/1.0/build/ for more information.
nsantos@NS-PC:~$
```

And the content of the log file is:

```
DKMS make.log for dpx-1.0 for kernel 3.0.0-14-generic (i686)
Thu Jan 19 11:07:54 WET 2012
make -C /lib/modules/3.0.0-14-generic/build M=/var/lib/dkms/dpx/1.0/build modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-14-generic'
  CC [M]  /var/lib/dkms/dpx/1.0/build/dpxmtt.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/dpx/1.0/build/dpx.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /var/lib/dkms/dpx/1.0/build/dpx.mod.o
  LD [M]  /var/lib/dkms/dpx/1.0/build/dpx.ko

make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.0.0-14-generic'
```

The module was built correctly but it ends with the error:

```
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for dpx: 1.0 not found
Error!  Build of dpx.ko failed for: 3.0.0-14-generic (i686)
```

And I don't know what it means. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 2):

Using:

`$(shell uname -r)`

in the Makefile it might be also wrong! The "shell uname -r" refers to the currently running kernel, but the main reason to use the dkms it's because it offers an automated method to recompile the kernel modules that reside outside of the kernel tree for every newly installed kernel. What i mean is that the Makefile might refers to a different kernel which the dkms is building the module for.

Use:

`${kernelver}` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I think your `BUILT_MODULE_LOCATION` is set incorrectly to the `src` directory. It should be set in your example to the current directory, or you can just omit this variable and dkms would default to the current directory.